# File upload issue, redirecting to error page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I have written 'upload file' code in the controller. Everything is working fine. But my tester asked me 'What happens if I choose a file from my system and rename that file name before clicking on upload'. I have checked this scenario. Chrome browser is redirecting me to an err_file_not_found page where as Firefox is displaying a blank page. I tried exception handling also but not able to handle this.
Following is the code. It is not even checking the else part. Please help me with this issue.

```
public function addFile()
{   
$fileDetails =  array('file' =>'@'. $_FILES['component_id']['tmp_name'].';filename='.$_FILES['component_id']['name'].';type='.   $_FILES['component_id']['type']);  
$uploadResponse = $this->component_model->imageupload(UPLOAD_FILE,$fileDetails);  
$filepath = $_FILES['component_jar_id']['tmp_name'];
if(file_exists($filepath)){
echo "success"; 
}
else{
echo "Requested file not found";
}       
}
```

I have changed my code as follows.

```
public function addFile()
{ 
    try{    
        $fileDetails =  array('file' =>'@'. $_FILES['component_jar_id']['tmp_name']. ';filename=' . $_FILES['component_jar_id']['name']. ';type=' . $_FILES['component_jar_id']['type']);  
        $uploadResponse1 = $this->component_model->imageupload(UPLOAD_FILE,$fileDetails); 
        $config['upload_path'] = $_FILES['component_jar_id']['tmp_name'];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            throw new Exception("File not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Still chrome is redirecting to webpage not found and on refreshing, it is showing the exception i have thrown.

Comment: Please provide the code that you tried

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it now

Comment: What exactly would you like to happen? The file does not exist when you are trying to upload it so you are getting the correct error. I would personally add a check on the upload handler that the file exists and throw an exception if not. (See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Also, "your tester" should be telling you his expected behaviour, asking what-ifs are a lot more helpful if you know expected behaviour.

Comment: In this scenario, the form submit should tell that **File not found** error. Since there is no file with the name while you upload

Comment: @AaronCritchley I want to show an error in my webpage if file does not exist. Instead the browser is redirecting to some other pages. I don't want that. It is not checking the else part i have written. It is blindly redirecting to web page not found or a blank page

Comment: @Priyanka It seems like your check is in the wrong place. You're checking AFTER you've tried to upload, move the check (and the creation of the needed variables) to the start of the code, you should be throwing an exception or returning null, after an echo the code will continue to execute and break.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Aaron. But i didn't get you clearly. Can you please send me sample code or modify my above code about how to do that

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/02/image-file-upload-in-codeigniter-validations-examples.html) explains clearly to know how form process should done in CodeIgniter. See this

Comment: No use Gunaseelan. Facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your case is like you have explained then check for

```
 $_FILES["component_id"]["size"]
```

`$_FILES["component_id"]["size"] will become 0` in case you change the file name after browsing, so you can write something like.

```
if($_FILES["component_id"]["size"] > 0){
echo "success"; 
}
else{
echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tarun. This is working in Firefox browser. But in Chrome browser the issue is still the same. It is redirecting to web page not found page and on refreshing that page it is showing fail message.

Comment: Hey, Yes I can see that happening too.which version of chome you are on?

Comment: Version 43.0.2357.130

Comment: Just now updated my chrome browser but still facing the same problem. Everything is going fine in all browsers except this. Have to find out how to resolve this

Comment: I am also working to find a way to resolve this problem in chrome.. Do you have any suggestions??

Comment: Priyanka - I cannot see a solution for this in chrome.. Chrome has its own file upload mechanism. I have check few big known websites and cannot find any website which has made this check.

Comment: Ask your testers to give you some references of the same.. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Tarun. I'll definitely talk to my Tester about this.